# Wordpress Taxonomy Archives

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

To learn about Wordpress, I am building my own theme. I have created a Custom Post Type (CPT) called `Golf Courses [golf-courses]`.

The CPT has hierarchical taxonomies which I have named (whilst learning) and laid out as follows:

```
Europe
 - UK
  - England
```

I then have a custom function that rewrites the URL so it would appear like this:

`http://www.site.com/Europe/UK/England/stoke-park/`

For what I am doing, my custom posts will not be in a child taxonomy without being in its parent (so for the example URL above it would never be in UK and not Europe as well).

What I am now trying to do without much luck is list all the posts in say UK under a URL like:

`http://www.site.com/Europe/UK/`

This doesn't work, but it seems such a simple concept that I don't see why not.

`http://www.site.com/Europe/` or `http://www.site.com/UK/` do work though.

What do I need to do to get this working, or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

When registering a new taxonomy add the `rewrite` parameter. In your case:

```
function build_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy( 'europe', 'homepage', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Europe', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => array( 'hierarchical' => true ) ) ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Then add UK and then Stoke and nest stoke under UK (parent).

(also try [flush your rewrite rules](http://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) after you've added the code)

Comment: Mark, I'm a little confused by how to do the nesting of stoke under UK that you mention. Any chance you can expand the answer to include an example?

Comment: @neildeadman add a new category called UK and by parent category select Europe

Comment: Oh right, I thought it was some sort of nesting of register_taxonomy commands.. categories and not custom taxonomies :/